# which spellchecker to use with PHP

Tags: php, spell-checking

Currently I am using Spellify for my project but its creating problem in ie7 and some people don't like pressing ignore every time. i have checked aspell and pspell. Can any one please suggest better spell checking utility with PHP.

or something like one time spell checking. once form is filled before submitting it ask for spell check and call spell checker at this time not while they are typing.

any help much appriciated.

any open source or free.

Many thanks

Comment: http://www.phpspellcheck.com/

Comment: its not free... sorry to mention i am after open source.

Comment: You could check the post after submission using http://php.net/manual/en/ref.pspell.php

Comment: @RJ45.. you are right... i like jspell. do you know similar utility open source?

Answer (score -2, accepted):

At last i found what i was looking for.

http://www.broken-notebook.com/spell_checker/

Really thanks to all people who has given their inputs.

Comment: The link is unfortunately dead

Answer (score 4):

PHP has an extension called `Pspell`:

http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.pspell.php

Which is free and open source.

Comment: I have looked at this but not sure will still be same issue as with specify.

Comment: @henna perhaps you should be more specific then.

Comment: i am looking at http://www.jspell.com/ajax-spell-checker.html
will update if i find something

Comment: @henna are you saying pspell is not free? It is a GNU product!

Answer (score 2):

You may use spell checking library such as

- [phpspellcheck](http://www.phpspellcheck.com/)
- [tinymce](http://www.tinymce.com/wiki.php/Plugin%3aspellchecker)
  This gives suggestions too.

Comment: thanks for you answer. will look at tinymce spellcheck.